# Angular dispersion of a diffraction grating

Tags: diffraction

I am not sure what is '$a$' according to the angular dispersion formula below.
The formula is

$$
\frac{d\theta}{d\lambda}=\frac{m}{a\cos\theta}
$$

Is it the distance between two consecutive slits?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since $Na$ is the grating width, $a$ must be the period of the grating. It is not exactly the same as the distance between the slits, but rather this distance + the slit width.

Answer (score 0):

In the equations given, ‘a’ is simply the groove spacing, i.e., the reciprocal of the grating’s groove per mm specification. For example, if the grating is specified as having 300 grooves/mm, then a = 0.00333 mm/groove. Since N is the number of usefully illuminated grating grooves, the product Na has units of mm, i.e., number of grooves times mm/groove. Maximizing Na is beneficial, other things equal.